# Collecting to a vector instead of a list

Tags: vector, iteration, common-lisp

I solved Project Euler's 8th problem using SBCL and the `iterate` package from quicklisp. In my code I defined a function that turns a number into a list of it's digits. Here's the source code:

```
(defun number-to-list (n)
  (iter (for c in-string (write-to-string n)) (collect (digit-char-p c))))
```

The `collect` clause both in `iter` and in `loop` make a list out of the values. Is it possible to instead generate a vector (one dimensional array)?

Would my only option be to convert the list generated by `number-to-list` to a vector? Because that seems inefficient (although probably not *that* inefficient)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually there is one big problem: how large will the result vector be? It would be best to know that upfront, then we can allocate the vector once with the correct size. Otherwise we would have find ways to deal with that: use a resizable vector, allocate a list first and copy into a result vector later, allocate a larger vector with a fill pointer, ...

If you have a sequence, then one can use the Common Lisp function `MAP`: if the source object is a vector, here a string, its length is cheap to get.

```
CL-USER 1 > (map 'vector
                 #'digit-char-p
                 (write-to-string 5837457324534))
#(5 8 3 7 4 5 7 3 2 4 5 3 4)
```

You can use `ITERATE` and collect a vector:

```
FOO 32 > (defun number-to-vector (n)
           (iter (for c in-string (write-to-string n))
             (collect (digit-char-p c) result-type vector)))
NUMBER-TO-VECTOR

FOO 33 > (number-to-vector 8573475934)
#(8 5 7 3 4 7 5 9 3 4)
```

If you look at the macro expansion, it actually collects into a list and then calls `COERCE` to create the vector. So: no win in efficiency.

Note that this is another example where `ITERATE` is more powerful than `LOOP`: the standard `LOOP` can't directly return vectors from *collect*.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll use the more functional approach since the whole reason I'm doing Project Euler in CL is to avoid ugly code (I did a few problems in C and my uncle helped me optimize them, thinking about all the bits and bytes drove me insane)

Comment: Now that I have a pretty and performant (it should perform well right?) solution I have 2 mini-problems (I'll split them into 2 comments):

Comment: I'd like to make a project. I'm aware of quickproject but I can't figure out the best way to represent this project. Should I define a package for each problem? 1 package for all problems? Split everything across different lisp files as opposed to putting all the solutions in 1 big lisp file? If so, the how can I "link" the files together when compiling?

Comment: I'd like to compile it to a Windows executable (would use Linux but I only have my dad's computer). How can I do that? (I know how to compile a single file to a fasl and to an exe but how would one go about compiling a whole project?)

Comment: @omrisim210: Personally I would use just one file. You usually create executables by saving an executable image. It does not matter how many files you have loaded into Lisp.

Comment: So to generate an executable from multiple files I just have to load them all into the current lisp instance and `save-lisp-and-die`? Cool, I'll consider it.

Answer (score 2):

The proposed solutions are correct and elegant, but they first create a list, or trasform the number in string. I would like to propose a direct transformation from integers to arrays, without transforming first the number in a list or a string:

```
(defun digits(n)
  "Transform a positive integer n in array of digits"
  (let* ((logn (floor (log n 10)))
         (result (make-array (1+ logn) :element-type '(integer 0 9))))
    (loop for i downfrom logn to 0
       do (setf (values n (aref result i)) (floor n 10)))
    result))
```

The problem of allocating an array of the correct dimension is solved with the formula that gives the number of decimal digits of an integer n:  ⌊log<sub>10</sub> n⌋+1.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, looks like it'll be pretty efficient but CL is like my "escape language" from C (where I have to use all these math tricks to operate on numbers and if I do have to resort to strings I need to dynamically allocate them). Transforming the number into a string and the string into a vector is enough for me.

Comment: Notice that `LOG` expects a non-zero number, so `(digits 0)` should be handled separately.

Comment: @jkiiski, you are correct, for this reason I specified in the comment string that the function is only for positive integers.

Comment: You don't need `multiple-value-bind`: `(setf (values n (aref result i)) (floor n 10))`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not a direct answer to your question but here are my num-to-list and list-to-num functions I frequently use.

```
(defun num-to-list-helper (n liste)
  (cond ((< n 1) liste)
    (t (num-to-list-helper (truncate (/ n 10)) (cons (rem n 10) liste))))))

(defun num-to-list (n)
  (num-to-list-helper n nil))

(defun list-to-num-helper (liste n)
  (if (null liste)
      n
      (list-to-num-helper (cdr liste)
              (+ n (* (car liste) (expt 10 (1- (length liste))))))))
(defun list-to-num (liste)
  (list-to-num-helper liste 0))
```

You could try these and see if there's an improvement over converting the number to string. Personally I don't prefer strings for numbers as I consider them as an ugly trick I was forced to do in my Java days.

You could also convert these functions to a version using vectors and see how they do.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your functions but I'd like to have simple code that I can understand instead of just copying a "magic solution" from the internet, and this code isn't particularly easy to understand without stepping through the whole thing (mentally or with a debugger)

Comment: @omrisim210 Try `trace`ing the helper functions. You'll see how each parameter changes every step of the way. The real work is done by the "helper" functions. They are recursive. They take one argument, work on it, collect the result in the second argument, and they call themselves with a shorter or smaller version of the first argument. They stop when the first argument is either too small or null (depending on whether it is a number or list). `trace` is your friend.

Comment: I will do so soon, right now I'm taking a break because my brain hurts from all the problem solving :)